# Call a function at end of the script in Python

Tags: python, function, call

So far I have been getting a lot of help and been able to successfully put together a Python script. The script basically calls a Windows executable and then does some action like pulling down some files from a remote server. And at the end of the script I have a function which does a compression and moves the retrieved files to another server. So far the script was working great, but now looks like I have hit a road hurdle.

The script basically accepts a ParentNumber as a input and finds 1 or more ChildNumbers. Once the list of ChildNumbers are gathered the script goes calls the windows executable with the number repeatedly till it completes pulling data for all of them.

As mentioned above the Function I have built to Archive, Move Files and Email Notification is being called at end of the script, the function works perfectly fine if there is only one ChildNumber. If there are many ChildNumbers and when the executable moves on the 2nd ChildNumber the command line kinda treats it as end and stats with new line something like below:

```
.........
C:\Scripts\startscript.py
Input> ParentNumber
Retrieval started 
Retrieval finished
**Email Sent Successfully**
Preparing ParentNumber @childNumber

C:\Scritps\ParentNumber123\childNumber2
Retrieval Started
Retrieval finished
.........
```

`
If you see the script flow above the Email Sent successfully message shows up under first ChildNumber only, which means it's called way before the completion of the script.

The actual behavior I want is that all ArchiveMoveEmailFunction should be called once all of the ChildNumbers are processed, but not sure where it's going wrong.

My function for the ArchiveMoveEmailFunction as below and it's at ending of all other lines in the script:

```
def archiveMoveEmailNotification(startTime, sender, receivers):
"""
Function to archive, move and email
"""
Code for Archive
Code for Move to remote server
Code for email
archiveMoveEmailNotification(startTime, sender,receivers)
```

Please let me know if I am missing something here to specify on when exactly this function should be executed. As mentioned it works totally fine if the ParentNumber has only 1 ChildNumber, so not sure if the second retrieval jump is causing some issue here. Is there a way I can just have this function wait till rest of the functions in the script are called or would be be logical to move this function to another script completely and call that function from the master script?

Here is the exe call part:

```
def execExe(childNumb):

cmd = "myExe retriveeAll -u \"%s\" -l \"%s\"" % (childNum.Url(),childAccount.workDir))
return os.system(cmd)

def retriveChildNumb(childNumb):

#Run the retrive
if not (execExe(childNumb)==0):
    DisplayResult(childNumb,3)
else:
    DisplayResult(childNumb,0)

return 0
```

Any inputs thoughts on this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is verbose but hard to understand; providing the code would make this much easier to troubleshoot.

That said, my suspicion is that the code you're using to call the Windows executable is asynchronous, meaning your program continues (and finishes) without waiting for the executable to return a value.

Comment: Totally agree with you I am very much a beginner for python and trying to make enhancement to an existing piece of code, so having difficulty understanding stuff. As far as the return value, the program does finish with return value and there is a dictionary maintained for the the return values in the same script for logging. I have appended the exe call part in the original question.

Comment: Comments don't handle code very well, please update your question with the relevant code.

Comment: os.system() should not be asynchronous (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system), so that appears not to be the issue. You might share the rest of your code and someone may be able to help you. I don't see a recursive call to execExe, so that would be the next thing to look for.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. Looks like I figured out the issue. There was just a threading.Thread call which I had to change for the recursive call.. Thanks again @Nathan Fig